# GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

**Note:** Before you mark it as duplicate, please read the question fully.

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 normally, but today when I turned my laptop on, and selected Ubuntu out of two options: Windows and Ubuntu, the following screen appeared:

[image]

I searched this a lot on here, but couldn't find a working solution.

One solution suggested me that I should do first `ls` in different partitions and see where the file `vmliuz` or `initrd` resides. But I found no where these files.

I also played with the brightness of my laptop, which may be a cause of this stuck screen.

**Edit 1:**

I'm still unable to find the directory that contains the `initrd.img` file.

```
grub> ls 
(memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
grub> set pager=1
grub> ls (memdisk)/
wubuilder.cfg
grub> ls (hd0)/
error: unknown filesystem.
grub> ls (hd0,3)/
$AttrDef $BadClus $Bitmap $Boot $Extend/ $LogFile $MFT $MFTMirr $RECYCLE.BIN/ $Secure $UpCase $Volume ./ Code School/ Downloads/ Movies/ System Volume Information/ ubuntu/ wubuilder
grub> ls (hd0, 2)/
Programming Files (x86)/ Users/ $AttrDef $BadClus $Bitmap $Boot $Extend/ $LogFile $MFT $MFTMirr $RECYCLE.BIN/ $Secure $UpCase $Volume ./ Documents and Settings/ hiberfil.sys Intel/ MSOCache/ pagefile.sys PerfLogs/ Program Files/ ProgramDAta/ Recovery/ Setup/ swsetup/ System Volume Information/ Windows/ wubildr wubildr.mbr
grub> ls (hd0, 1)/
$AttrDef $BadClus $Bitmap $Boot $Extend/ $LogFile $MFT $MFTMirr $RECYCLE.BIN/ $Secure $UpCase $Volume ./ Boot/ bootmgr BOOTSECT.BAK System Volume Information/
```

**Edit 2:**

Also, please note that I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. And my Ubuntu resides at the following location; I checked it by booting up Windows OS:

```
grub ls (hd0,3)/ubuntu/
install/ uninstall-wubi.exe winboot/
```

Comment: Yes, I used `/` at the end. But my format was `ls (hdx,msdosy)/`, and `x` and `y` being numbers. Should I do `ls /boot/` as well to see that the mentioned files exist there or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**If you have installed without Wubi.exe:**

At the `grub` prompt try these commands:

```
set pager=1
ls
```

Now, suppose the output of `ls` is: `(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`, in order to find the linux root filesystem run:

`ls (hd0,1)/`
 which should give you all the files/folders in `/` such as `bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/` etc.

Once this is done continue with:

```
set root=(hd0,1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
boot
```

Of course replace `vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic` and `initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic` with what you find in your `/boot`

`/dev/sda1` is the location of the root system. You may have to change it if `/dev/sda1` did not work.

**If you have installed using Wubi.exe:**

If you have installed Ubuntu using Wubi, perform following steps as given in the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

1. boot into Windows, run `chkdsk /r` from Windows on the same drive where you installed Ubuntu, shutdown cleanly and then try to boot into Ubuntu again.
2. if still not good, check that you have a `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` file. If this file is missing, boot on Windows, open the `Windows Explorer`, set it to be able to see hidden folders, then look for a hidden folder called `C:\found.000` or `dir0000.chk` . Move the files from found.000 to their original location inside the `\ubuntu\disks` directory. You may have to rename it into `root.disk`.

Comment: I followed your steps, but I'm unable to find `/boot/` so far. I've updated my question, please review it.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Did you use `wubi installer`

Comment: Yes @Ron, I installed it through wubi installer. I did it a long time ago.

Comment: Oh man! It worked finally. I followed the same instructions as you wrote in your **edit** but form somewhere else. Could you please change the order, and move the last written instructions related to `\disks\root.disk` to upward - that seems right - this way it will benefit mostly, and I'm gonna accept your answer. Really thanks.

Comment: Please note that the most probable cause of this problem was to force shutdown the OS.

Comment: @ArslanAli My suggestion is to install ubuntu using a LiveCD/ USB than using Wubi. There seems to be lot of problems using wubi. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but this doesn't solv it. Info: My partitions are all "gptX", no msdos despite dual boot, one is called (proc), the linux partition seems to be (hd0,gpt8) and I have a lot more vmlinuz versions. When I run the commands, using sda1 or 8 and replacing with latest vmlinuz/initrd version, it goes to "no root device specified....." above "Busybox v1.30.1 .... (initramfs)"  How can I make it boot? into any OS? I don't min reinstalling the Linux partition, just so long as I can get my laptop back!

Answer (score 14):

Run those commands

```
grub> linux  (hd0,1)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd  (hd0,1)/initrd.img
grub> boot
```

Replace `hd0` with your hdd number  and /dev/sda1 with your partition holding the /boot mainly the dafult will work if you don't have more than one hdd and with default installtion

[check this for more info](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/)

When you can boot again you should fix your problem

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use `(hd0,msdos1)` instead of `(hd0,1)`?

Comment: It works either

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to find that partition. What I'm getting is: I've updated in the question, please review it.

Comment: @Maythux I did `sudo update-grub` but after restart, it happend again