# How do I use GRUB rescue?

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

So when I was starting my computer, I pressed <kbd>F8</kbd> and then it said there was no such partition and now it only shows GRUB rescue. How do I fix GRUB to run normally again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Run those commands replacing with suitable for your system

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,1)
grub rescue> insmod linux
grub rescue> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub rescue> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub rescue> boot
```

Please taek a look for my answer here [GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen/616814#616814)

Also Please take a look for this link https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/

---

#### Another solution to boot from livecd and reinstall the Grub

- put ubuntu live cd of the same version of your sysetm
- boot with try ubuntu without installing

Then run those commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Identify the boot partition with * besied suppose /dev/sda1

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt 
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo reboot
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I also have windows on my computer as /dev/sda2. Doing this won't mess it up will it?

Comment: It shall not mess your Windows

Comment: When I did the insmod normal command, it said unknown filesystem

Comment: I only get a black screen when I use and live DVD and try to use ubuntu without installing.

Comment: @Shempklong you have to use the same version of your Ubuntu system already installed

Comment: Yes it's 14.04.

Comment: @Shempklong i delete the insomd normal check the edit

Comment: said unknown filesystem with insmod linux too.

Comment: Well I did and now it uploads Gnu Grub, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To rescue your grub, you can use [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair) tool.This tool helps me lot, every time i troubleshoot grub problems.

Before starting rescue operation, first you need a Ubuntu in bootable USB flash drive or Ubuntu Disk .

- Plug Disk or Flash drive and enter into **Try Ubuntu** mode.
- Connect your system with internet.
- Open Terminal by pressing **CTRL+ALT+T**.
- Type these commands in terminal.

  ```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
  ```
- Click on the options which will shown in the boot-repair window.
- Wait for some minutes, and it will repair you grub automatically.You don't need to worry about anything.Just click on options and move forward.

Comment: I only get a black screen when I try to use the live DVD for some reason.

Comment: @Shempklong, use bootable flash drive option.

Comment: I don't have it on a flashdrive. Is there anyway to put it from the cd to the flashdrive?

Comment: @Shempklong, for that you need a working machine. As currently your machine is not working, you need another machine for making Flash Drive bootable from you Ubuntu CD.

Comment: i have one, i'm using one right now.

Comment: @Shempklong, what OS you are using right now??

Comment: i'm in windows.

Comment: @Shempklong, first you have to form a **ISO** file from your Ubuntu CD [Click here for instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11003/how-to-create-a-windows-iso-from-a-disc-using-imgburn/).Then, after that you can make bootable Flash Drive using this **ISO**. [Click here for instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: @Shempklong, you can also use [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/download.htm) tool for making **ISO**.

Comment: it only shows a black screen on the flash drive too

Comment: @Shempklong, had you followed right method to boot your machine from external Flash drive??? or you simply plugged it and start your machine and press nothing(Key Combination) to get bootup mode screen.  i am just trying to understand your problem.

Comment: I booted it from the flash drive and then clicked try ubuntu and all it shows is a black screen.

Comment: @Shempklong, try to download a new **ISO** of Ubuntu 14.04 or any Ubuntu version from ubuntu website.Do the above mentioned process.

Comment: It'll start now but it keeps frezeing because of the graphics card driver. One problem after another.

Comment: and by it'll start, i mean oi can boot it from the flash drive, not that I fixed my original problem.

Comment: I got it working and it said that everything failed.

Comment: @Shempklong, at what step it shows `failed ` message. Could you describe it ???

Comment: All of the stuff it tried to load in the terminal, had "failed" after it.

Comment: I was able to do it and now it just loads gnu grub insteaad of grub rescue. What can you do now?

Comment: @Shempklong, Could you post a screenshot of it , because i am little bit confuse by your above comments ??

Comment: Oops I got you confused with someone else who answered my question. I did something else besides boot repair. I tried to boot the partition and then install grub onto it and now a have a GNU grub screen instead of a grub rescue screen and I'm equally as confused by it.

Comment: @Shempklong, in GNU grub screen, what options are shown ?? I think in the screen there must be a booting list of OS installed on your machine. [Link to Image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/GRUB_screenshot.png).

Comment: There isn't, it says I have to load the kernel.