# How do I get out of the endless cycle of GNU GRUB terminal?

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, grub2

I had a problem, and found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen)

I have installed ubuntu hundreds of times, but first time having this problem.

After the install, I always get to the `GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.4` terminal.

I'm able to boot into the correct place on the machine using the following commands from the answer below

```
set root=(hd0,1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-39-generic root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-39-generic
boot
```

Once I run those commands, I'm booted into my terminal...

As a side note, on the second command `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-39-generic root=/dev/sda1`, If I try to auto complete the /dev/sda1, it won't....like it's not there.

And if I run `ls (hd0,1)/dev/` then sda1 also isn't there.....however

Once I run `boot` and log in, I can see `/dev/sda1`

At any rate, the new problem is that when I reboot the computer, I get to this grub terminal every single time.

I have tried, after logging into the machine, running `update-grub`, and that doesn't work.

I also tried installing and using boot-repair from [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) instructions.

I did get a warning out of the boot-repair...

```
gcfontool-2:6097): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

I'm not sure that has anything to do with the problem though.

side side note....add-apt-repository wasn't installed by default, so I had to install using [this](http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/)

Some background info, this is a brand new SuperMicro server with a single HDD.  It used to have two, but I took one out just to make sure I wasn't accidentally installing GRUB in weird places.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting my question, I realized that the answer on that page I mentioned left out a step, but linked to the correct solution.

after running

```
update-grub
```

I also needed to run

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Blah, I guess now at least it's here, and not just on an external link.

Comment: If anyone knows, I'd be super interested in knowing why this happened?  I re-installed ubuntu 5 or 6 times, and tried 14.04 and 15.04 and the same thing happened on this machine every time.