# Grub terminal-no filesystems recognised

Tags: boot, grub2, lvm

I've followed the instructions here [GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen?answertab=oldest&newreg=a2de62419d0f4316a48999c40d812716) but it can't read any of the disks.

I'm getting 'Filesystem is unknown', 'filesystem is ext2' etc.

It's a server edition install. I stupidly selected LVM and was interrupted during the install. However, I can't now get back to bios to reset the boot order and reinstall.

Below is an image of the output from grub> ls I can't copy and paste, as the machine is well and truly stuck.

Photo of my grub screen:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you get into the BIOS?

Comment: I just have. I was about to put up an apologetic comment. I tried a dozen times and it just went to the grub screen, then, holding the esc key down in irritation, it worked! Sorry to have bothered you. Thanks for answering.