# GNU Grub screen after installing update

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, uefi

I was installing additional software to be able to do backups. Suddenly my computer restarted and ever since then only the GNU Grub screen shows up. I tried the commands on another forum ([GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen)) but it didn't work. I tried "ls" and it said I have gpt drives (whatever those are). I changed the boot from UEFI secure to UEFI with secure boot off to be able to do this.

I'm a noob, help me out please! I don't want to lose any of my data.

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Only Ubuntu, I replaced Windows 10 with it.

[What happens after I put in ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6cEe.jpg)

[On startup. If I try to load Ubuntu, the screen goes blank and the light on the Caps Lock key flashes. Nothing else happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCf5s.jpg)

UPDATE : Sorry, it's UEFI with secure boot off, not legacy. I ran the "diagnostics" option from the system startup and checked everything, all the results were normal. Tje diagnostics tool seems to think my hard drive is functioning but can't boot Ubuntu for some reason.

Comment: Can you access Alt + ctrl + F2?

Comment: @learner i pressed that and nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have experienced hardware failure (either transient, such as overheating, or permanent, such as defective disk or memory) and subsequent corruption of your hard disk / SSD.  Since you mention you have important files on this system, I would strongly recommend booting from a LiveCD and copying those files to a removable storage device before attempting to recover or reinstall your Ubuntu installation.

Can you provide more details on what you see on your GRUB screen from a fresh boot?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that... I have to get help with this

Comment: Also, the second link to an image: that is exactly what I see. I only get the grub> line when i press Escape

Answer (score 0):

> I changed the boot from UEFI secure to Legacy with secure boot off to be able to do this.

First, reverse this action! You've complicated your boot path in a way that's likely to create more problems in the future. For more on why enabling the CSM (aka "legacy boot" support) is likely to cause problems, see my page on the subject:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html

With that done, there are several approaches to fixing your problem:

**Option 1: Methodical Analysis and Repair**

The first method is to analyze your current boot situation and, using what you learn, decide on a repair approach. The best tool for analysis is the [Boot Info Script.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) When you run it from an emergency disk, it will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`, which contains lots of diagnostic information on your computer.

Combined with sufficient knowledge, `RESULTS.txt` will probably tell you why the boot failed; however, note that first clause. To the uninitiated, the `RESULTS.txt` file will be gibberish. Thus, if you lack that knowledge, you'll need to upload that file to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) post the URL here or to some other forum, and hope that somebody can get back to you with an analysis and suggested repair.

**Option 2: Use rEFInd to Boot and Repair**

You can download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) write it to a suitable medium, and boot from it. With any luck, this will work and enable you to boot. You can then run Boot Info Script to learn more or try to blindly re-install GRUB (with `sudo grub-install`, perhaps followed by `sudo update-grub`) or install rEFInd (via its Debian package or PPA).

One big caveat is that the rEFInd images I provide won't boot if Secure Boot is active, so if Secure Boot is active, you'll need to disable it, at least temporarily. (Alternatively, you could add Secure Boot support to a USB flash drive image, but that will require jumping through some extra hoops.)

Of course, rEFInd won't work if your Ubuntu installation has somebody vanished, but at least it won't do any harm in this situation.

**Option 3: Use Boot Repair and Hope it Works**

A third option is to use the [Boot Repair utility,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which installs a fresh copy of GRUB on the computer and reconfigures it. This tool *usually* works to fix boot problems; but in some cases it gets things wrong. It's also likely to fail in unpredictable ways if something really bad has happened to your installation (like if the Ubuntu partition has been deleted).

**Summary**

The safest approach is to methodically diagnose your problem and choose a repair based on what you learn. Using Boot Repair is a shot-in-the-dark approach that stands a good chance of working, but without knowing what's wrong, it's also hard to assess the dangers of using this tool. Using rEFInd is in-between these two approaches. Note that there are hybrids; for instance, you could use rEFInd to boot and then run Boot Repair to gain more information. You might also decide to run Boot Repair or install rEFInd after running the Boot Info Script.