# Cannot boot after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: grub2, upgrade, updates, 17.10

I just upgraded to the new 17.10 ubuntu, then rebooted my PC.

However, now it cannot boot up.
All I see is a purple screen with a grub> command prompt.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

I just used a boot repair disc to fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)