# Unwanted GRUB2 boot menu at startup + Ubuntu won't start

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, startup, intel-nuc

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on an Intel NUC (there is no other OS and no dual boot). Probably due to involuntarily pressing keys during startup (right shift i suppose), i am now getting the GRUB2 boot menu at each startup.

Moreover, the default "Ubuntu" option in the menu restarts the NUC (i get the NUC BIOS screen) only to get back to the GRUB2 menu. This loops forever, so Ubuntu won't launch that way.

By accessing the command prompt from the GRUB2 menu, i have successfully launched Ubuntu by using Ron's answer to the following question:

[GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen)

Ubuntu then seems to work correctly, and at first glance, all my programs and data are still there.

I checked the GRUB2 settings, and the following properties are set:
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

How can i repair my boot sequence, i.e. hide the GRUB2 boot menu and launch Ubuntu automatically without having to use the command line?

Comment: Whenever Ubuntu does not correctly shutdown, a flag is set and grub menu is shown, so you can use recovery mode if needed to make repairs. Or just boot normally if no other issues. Often after an abnormal shutdown fsck may be required. Can you boot recovery mode?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately no, booting in recovery mode from the GRUB2 menu has the same behavior: the device reboots and gets back to the GRUB2 menu. I'll try fsck since i can still access the command prompt.

Comment: I successfully ran fsck from Ubuntu Live USB, but no errors were detected. I also reinstalled grub since that was mentioned elsewhere as a potential solution, but that didn't solve either problem...

Comment: Did you do a  full uninstall/reinstall of grub2? That would reset everything back to defaults. Does system seem to shutdown normally?

Comment: Twice now i've done a full reinstall of the whole OS from a USB drive (just as i did initially). Both times the system worked normally for a few days then the symptom would reappear... I don't understand: it had worked beautifully for more than a year. What could cause this?

Comment: I do not know. About all I can suggest is running Boot-Repair's Summary Report right after install when it is working the way you want. And then when it stops working correctly run another copy of Report and see if you have any differences using meld or similar difference software.