# GNU GRUB terminal screen when upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu to the recently released 18.04 LTS from the 16.04 version. After the install when I powered it off and then on, I was taken to the GRUB screen instead of the normal booting. I tried to follow the steps in the this answer here: [GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen)

Here's a run down of what I have typed:

> set pager=1
>   set root=(hd0, 1)
>   linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=/dev/sda1
>   initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
>   boot

That showed me some error in `initramfs` shell like

> ALERT /dev/sda1 does not exit dropping to shell

I realised that my root system location might not be in sda1. So, I tried the steps again with different `sda`'s. When I am doing that I now get this error:

> error: disk `(hd0, ' not found.

Please help.

Comment: Don't do these lines randomly you can use command `ls /dev/sda{1,2..}` and verfify which one is root.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you @Debian_yadav. How do I verify my root again? Typing exactly `ls /dev/sda{1,2..}` gives an invalid file name error. I'm sorry for asking such a naive question :/

Comment: By {1,2...} I meant try `/dev/sda1` then `/dev/sda2` that is a variable entry. And it not solution it is to improve your method of searching.

Comment: Please provide the output of typing `ls`.