# error booting linux from grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have the same problem as this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/616811/745201).
I have followed it's [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/616821/745201) in this way:
I ran

```
set pager=1
ls
```

[This is the result of ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NHVp.png)

I found my linux root file system: (hd1,gpt7)
and ran the mentioned commands in the answer:
But I don't know what to put instead of `/dev/sda1`. In other words I don't know how what is the location of my root system.
I ran commands with `/dev/sda1` and get this result:

[this image is before pressing enter after entering "boot" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiaDT.png)

[result after pressing enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp4Yl.png)

I don't know what to do now! (I couldn't comment these informations under the answer because I don't have the enough reputation :/.

Comment: @Jeremy31 That worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Insert or connect the Ubuntu live media (DVD or USB).
Find out how to boot your computer from removable media.

Note that there is a difference between booting of older computers (BIOS/MBR) and newer ones designed for Windows 8 and later releases (UEFI/GPT).

Reboot the computer from live media and choose Try Ubuntu when asked.

Try Ubuntu

Connect to the internet, then open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t, paste the following commands and run them by pressing Enter:

`sudo apt install software-properties-common; \
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \
sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
Note: You copy and run them all at once. If you want to run them individually just remove the trailing "; \".

That's it, the Boot-Repair window will appear!

duplicate of [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)