# Unable to boot ubuntu 19.10 in dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I had a dual boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 19.10 with 90 GB of space. It was working perfectly fine. Then I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and I accidentally merged a 3.69 GB unallocated partition with a Windows volume. There is no problem with my windows. Then I tried to boot my Ubuntu, instead of the login screen I got a GNU grub terminal. Like this one - [GNU GRUB Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen)
. I tried doing boot-repair from live ubuntu. But there was no recommended repair. Here is my boot-repair log in [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fMZvZ4h9f8/). Will I be able to repair the ubuntu? If not, can I recover the files alone from my 90 GB ubuntu partition?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), but that's also your problem. Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Your tested & supported *release-upgrade* path is now also gone, as 18.10 upgraded to 19 04 which now too is EOL. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/   *In your case I'd suggest backing up data & install a supported release..*

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 18.10?  (or the 2018-October release), the 'live' media you used was not 18.10, but a supported (albeit outdated*) LTS or long-term-support release.

Comment: Sorry. It was 19.10. Not 18.10

Comment: From your boot-repair log, there doesn't seem to be an ext4 partition. I suspect your Win 8.1 upgrade may have overwritten your Ubuntu partition. I hope you had a backup of your files.

Comment: I didn't have a backup. So my 90 GB is just garbage? I need to be sure before I reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @ToDo Are you sure it's not recoverable?

Comment: Your best bet is to: 1. STOP using the computer. 2. Try testdisk from a liveUSB. However, since this was not simply a partitioning error, but an actual OS install, many files might have been overwritten for good. I have little experience with testdisk, but it can recover what is recoverable,