# After update can't boot, only terminal grub>

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot laptop, and the isssue is very similar to [this post 6 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen/616821#616821), but all my options are different and when I try to use the answer it doesn't work.

The problem occurred after a large firmware update, after which the normal grub menu stopped working (it booted straight into Windows). I could get it into linux though so I ran the boot-repair tool. Since then I can't boot anything, not even a chance to go into BIOS, it just goes straight to a black terminal screen with `grub>`

In short, the solution linked above says to use the following command, replacing (hd0,1) with whatever partition has linux.

```
set pager=1
ls
set root=(hd0,1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
boot
```

1. When I run `ls` the partitions are all (hd0, gptX), not msdos like
   the solution above, and one is called (proc). The linux partition
   seems to be (hd0,gpt8)
2. Next, I have a lot more vmlinuz versions, but I tried it with the
   most recent and corresponding initrd.
3. I don't know if I should be using sda1 or 8. I tried anyway and it
   goes to `no root device specified.....` and then `Busybox v1.30.1`
   and a prompt `(initramfs)`

   How can I make it boot? into any OS? I don't mind reinstalling the
   Linux partition, just so long as I can get my laptop back!

Comment: You should provide details of what OS you're using..   Your pasted detail refers to a 14.04 LTS/ESM kernel that is off-topic, yet your `busybox` package detail applies to a later release...   It's unclear what OS & release you're talking about as details don't match, and some are off-topic here.   If you understand what the example shows (which will match the OP in the question where it was found) you'll know how to adapt for your situation; comparing your box with the OP in questions you see will also help (are you using uEFI/BIOS etc.. was the OP in the question etc.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I'm so far put of my depth that I don't even know how to answer. The system is Linux Mint 20.1 with Windows 10 and a data partition. I can't run anything, there aren't any options, I can't make it use a live installer installer, I tried, but it goes straight from button-press to grub> in 4 seconds with no chance to choose anything, there's not even a splash screen.

Comment: PS: There isn't a pastebin boot-info summary report, it was offline when it ran, and it always worked before. And I don't know how to use "any working install", that's a large part of the problem. Sorry for being so clueless!